# error CS1501: No overload for method `ToString` takes '1' arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private int Score;

public void Update ()
{
    var t = ToString(Score);
    if (ElementCompleted == true)
    {
        Score += 1;
        ElementCompleted = false;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error:

> No overload for method `ToString` takes '1' arguments

Can anyone help me? I am not using `ToString` anywhere else in my project.

Answer (score 6):

Don't you mean to do `Score.ToString()`?

Otherwise, you are doing `this.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

it's telling you there is not a method toString() that takes 1 arguments because any toString method should always takes 0 arguments and you have sent it 1 argument score

Comment: Not correct. There are many ToString overloads that take a formatting argument, for example you could use `score.ToString("#,#")` to display 1,234 instead of 1234.